# A nome integral :$\int_0^1\text q(x)dx=1-\int_0^1\text q^{-1}(x) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, modular-forms, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

The [**Nome $\text q(x)$**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DedekindEtaFunction.html) is definable through  [Q-Series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/q-Series.html):

$$\int_0^1\text q(x)dx=\int_0^1 e^{-\frac{π\text K(1-x)}{\text K(x)
}}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nπ^nK^n(1-x)}{n!K^n(x)}dx=0.060860715078138363199942073390619015335823438347395182336964683032460302197228326471115422640020296331532494217887474046870237415480988255536107139568…$$

$0\le \text q(x)\le1 $:

[image]

This has  definition for the Nome when Mathworld gives one definition and the other gives the one above using the [Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticNomeQ/02/).
This integral is similar to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811490/family-of-definite-integrals-involving-dedekind-eta-function-of-a-complex-argume) with more information about the Dedekind Eta function.

Progress:

After some help from @Paramanand Singh, this result came up. Note the [Jacobi Theta functions $\vartheta_n(0,q)=\vartheta_n(q)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429766/jacobi-theta-functions?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C102.7244) and the [Q-Pochhammer Symbol $(a,b)_n,(a,a)_n=(a)_n$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html):

$$\int_0^1 \text q(x)dx=\int_0^1\frac{\vartheta_2^4(x) \vartheta_4^4(x)}{ϑ_3^4(x)}dx=\int_0^1 \left[\frac{2\sqrt[4]x\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^{2n}(1+x^{2n})^2\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^{2n})(1-x^{2n-1})^2}{\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^{2n})(1+x^{2n-1})^2}\right]^4dx=16\int_0^1 x\left[\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1+x^{2n})^2(1-x^{2n})(1-x^{2n-1})}{(1+x^{2n-1})^2}\right]^4dx=16\int_0^1 x\left[\frac{(x+1)^2(-1,x^2)_\infty^2\left(\frac 1x,x^2 \right)_\infty^2(x^2,x^2)_\infty}{4(x-1)^2\} \left(-\frac 1x,x^2 \right)_\infty^2 }\right]^4dx=\frac 1{16}\int_0^1\frac{x(x+1)^8(-1,x^2)_\infty^8\left(\frac 1x,x^2\right)_\infty^8(x^2)_\infty^4}{(x-1)^8 \left(-\frac 1x,x^2\right)_\infty^8}dx$$

Another form with [**Inverse Nome**](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/InverseEllipticNomeQ/): $$\int_0^1 \text q(x)dx =1-\int_0^1q^{-1}(x)=1-\int_0^1 \frac{\vartheta_2^4(x)}{\vartheta_3^4(x)}dx=1-16 \int_0^1 x \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{x^{2n}+1}{x^{2n-1}+1}\right)^8=1-16\int_0^1 \frac{(-1,x^2)_\infty^8}{\left(\frac 1x, x^2\right)_\infty^8}dx$$

Technically, the integral has a Maclaurin expansion, but there is no compact form with summation notation for the series coefficients. This idea can be seen with the [nome expansion](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticNomeQ/06/01/02/) and its [inverse’s](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/InverseEllipticNomeQ/06/01/02/) series. Simply using coefficients for the (inverse) nome expansion will not be a sufficient answer, the coefficients for the series should be explicitly or implicitly written. Note that the Inverse Nome is also called the [Elliptic Modulus](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=EllipticModulus&cid=431).

Comment: I suppose your $x$ is same as $k^2$.

Comment: We have $\frac{dq}{dx}=\frac{\pi^2q}{4k^2k'^2K^2}=\frac{q}{(2K/\pi)^2k^2k'^2}$. Your integral is thus $$\int_0^1\frac{\vartheta_2^4(q)\vartheta_4^4(q)}{\vartheta_3^4(q)}\,dq$$

Comment: I will check the product expansion of these theta functions to see if something nice comes up.